# Django 4.0 NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

So I'm learning to create a confirmation email address while registering an account using Django.

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('sign-up', views.sign_up, name='sign-up'),
    path('sign-in', views.sign_in, name='sign-in'),
    path('sign-out', views.sign_out, name='sign-out'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

I'm having this email_confirmation.html template:

```
{% autoescape off %}

Hello {{ name }}!

Please confirm your email by clicking on the following link.

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uid64=uid token=token %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

tokens.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator

from six import text_type

class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            text_type(user.pk) + text_type(timestamp)
        )

generate_token = TokenGenerator()
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def sign_up(request):

    # other code (didnt specify in this question)

        # Confirmation email

        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email_subject = "Email confirmation of My Page"
        confirmation_message = render_to_string('email_confirmation.html', {
            'name': user.first_name,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': generate_token.make_token(user),
        })
        email = EmailMessage(
            email_subject,
            confirmation_message,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [user.email],
        )

        email.fail_silently = True
        email.send()

        return redirect('sign-in')


    return render(request, "authentication/sign-up.html")

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    
    if user is not None and generate_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)

        return redirect("home")
    else:
        return render(request, 'activation_failed.html')
```

In the end, I am getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /sign-up
Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uid64': 'OA', 'token': 'ayjcvq-ae5426fe52cc9f8f5a545615ac9ef1c1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)/(?P<token>[^/]+)/\\Z']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/sign-up
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uid64': 'OA', 'token': 'ayjcvq-ae5426fe52cc9f8f5a545615ac9ef1c1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)/(?P<token>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

My question is, why I am getting this error and do you guys have any solution into it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url parameter is `activate/<uidb64>/<token>/`. parameter name is `uidb64` but you wrote `uid64` in your email template. Just replace uid64 to uidb64 like this

```
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Or you can write

```
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uid token %}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your url path to

```
path('activate/<uid64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Comment: To clarify: the path expects a keyword `uidb64`, but you pass `uid64` (without the b) when trying to reverse the url in the template: `{% url 'activate' uid64=uid token=token %}`